# Yanking multiple inner words in vim

Tags: vim

The inner and outer word text objects in vim behave differently when combined with a count. Given the text (cursor is within the word `first`)

```
first second third fourth
```

both `y2iw` will put the first word in the register, `y3iw`/`y4iw` the first two word etc. So I need at least `y7iw` to yank all four (inner) words. For outer words, the count given corresponds with the number of words yanked.

Why do two `iw` objects correspond to a single word in this case, and can I get `iw` to behave similar to `aw`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type 5 or so spaces and do `viw`: the 5 or so spaces are seleced because `iw` also considers `\s+` as a separate "object".

In your example, you have 7 `iw` objects:

- `yiw` yanks `first` in the unnamed register.
- `y2iw` yanks `first` (with the trailing space) in the unnamed register.
- `y3iw` yanks `first second` (with the space) in the unnamed register.
- `y4iw` yanks `first second` (with the spaces) in the unnamed register.
- And so on…

On the other hand, `aw` considers the word *and any number of following space* as an "object".

In your example, you have 4 `aw` objects:

- `yaw` yanks `first` (with the trailing space) in the unnamed register.
- `y2aw` yanks `first second` (with the trailing space) in the unnamed register.
- `y3aw` yanks `first second third` (with the trailing space) in the unnamed register.
- `y4aw` yanks `first second third fourth` in the unnamed register.

If you want `iw` to behave like `aw` just use `aw`.

Comment: Thanks! The Vim documentation defines a word as "a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space". That's why I did not expect a single space character to be treated as a word.